# How to find the sum of 1 to a user inputed number, Python

Tags: python, loops

I'm writing a program that asks the user for a number, then prints out the sum of all the numbers from 1 to that number:

```
Enter a number: 5
15
```

​
(The answer is 15 because 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 = 15).

So far I have:

```
n = int(input('Enter a number: '))
x = sum(1:n)
print(x)
```

But I'm not sure what the problem is, so could someone please help me.

Comment: [`x = n * (n+1) // 2`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF) ?

Comment: What did you expect `sum(1:n)` to do, exactly? What made you think `sum` took a single slice argument? That doesn't even work syntactically.

Comment: `x = sum(1:n)` where did you see this syntax before? It is not valid Python syntax.

Comment: How about: `x = sum(range(n+1))`

Answer (score 0):

Rob's answer (n*(n+1)//2) is the neatest algebraic solution.
If you want to do this by brute-force, you could try:

```
sum(range(1, n+1))
```

which adds up the numbers from 1 to n, the (n+1) being the (excluded) upper limit of the range.